# Extract string from string array

Tags: c++

I have an array of strings of "first last" names. 
On the file i have the names written as:

Abe Adams.

John Adams.

John Doe.

Sarah Smith.

I have stored these into a string, but without the period. What I want to do is separate first and last names into two different strings. Here is my code but it doesnt work? What am i doing wrong?

```
{
 int n = MAX;

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
     last[i] = substr(' ',',');


     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        first[i] = getline(cin,x[i],' ');
     }

      return;
 }
```

Comment: seems like you're missing a closing brace

Comment: You are using the same index variable i to iter your arrays ?

Comment: `substr` does not take chars as arguments... http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Comment: Could you possibly provide an example of *how exactly* they are stored, is it like "Abe Adams John Adams", or something different?

Comment: So then what should i use to extract the last names into an array

Comment: its stored as "first name" on new line, not next to each other

Comment: So it would be possible to split this 'string' via the new line (\n) character?

Comment: @jbutler483 No, that's not how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are reading your input from `stdin`, one (trivial) way to do this would be to read directly from `cin` as follows:

```
std::vector<std::string> first_names, last_names;

while (std::cin)
{
    std::string first_name, last_name;
    std::cin >> first_name >> last_name;
    first_names.push_back(first_name);
    last_names.push_back(last_name);
}
```

This works given the very simple format of your input, but anything more complex might not be so straightforward. It would be better as a general rule to read each line from the input into a string and process it there:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    // Do some stuff here with 'line', e.g.
    size_t space_pos = line.find_first_of(' ');
    std::string first_name = line.substr(0, space_pos);
    std::string last_name = line.substr(space_pos + 1);
}
```

This will give you more options such as using a string tokeniser or a regular expression pattern matcher to extract based on more complex criteria.

Naturally, if you aren't reading your name pairs from `stdin`, but from an array or vector instead, you can simply iterate over the collection and substitute `line` with the target of the iterator.

Comment: The question is *"What I want to do is separate first and last names into two different strings"* Can you explain in what way it does not answer the question? I've read it through a couple of times and I don't see how this doesn't solve the OPs problem.

Comment: I did read the question, did you? Do you see this bit: `first[i] = getline(cin,x[i],' ');`? Do you know what it means? How is it that you assume that the OP *likely* doesn't use `cin` when it's there in the code. I still don't understand how my answer is completely invalid. Why don't you provide an answer yourself if you have such insight?

Comment: I *am* providing an answer.

Comment: @Component10 Also note: [`while (!std::cin.eof())`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)!

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - Thanks for your constructive comment, I've made that change.

Comment: Ok- I admit I was wrong. My answer now has hardly any resemblance to your answer (apart from the parts I usually use), and I apologise.

Comment: @cybermonkey: Thanks. Apology accepted. No hard feelings :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your code:

- You are missing a closing brace
- `substr` does not take `char` as an argument

You can do this:

```
    std::vector<std::string> fns, lns;
    std::string fn, ln;

    bool hasinput = true;
    std::string inp;

    while (hasinput)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, inp);
        if (inp.empty())
        {
            hasinput = false;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            fn, ln = inp;
            fns.push_back(fn);
            lns.push_back(fn);
        }
    }
```

Don't forget these `#include`s:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

Comment: `_tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])` isn't standard c++. `using namespace std;` is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I never used `while(!cin.eof())` (in this answer).

Comment: you've used it in your [1st try](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27399171/revisions). I removed this critique from my comment meanwhile.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ True. I revised my answer to reflect your comments and also removed the Windows-specific example.

Comment: You should also note, that deleting a downvoted answer and giving another one, doesn't help much to prevent you being banned from answering. The deleted answer still counts.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, I know that. The same with questions. As long as I don't keep giving poor answers like my first try on this question I should be fine.